# How to send apk file from android device to wearable device?

Tags: java, android, wear-os

How to send apk file from android device to wearable device?
Having studied the official instructions, I did not understand what is best suited for this and is anything suitable for this at all? It seems like DataLayer is suitable for this, but it seems like Asset, and understand what is needed for this. I am sorry for my English! The problem is that I need to write an application that will download a watch face from a third-party resource from a link. More precisely, it is, but the code that works on the phone does not work on wearable devices.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know you have to sideload your apps.
There is a tuto, i haven't tested myself but it should work: [install legacy WearOS apps](https://9to5google.com/2021/04/17/install-sideload-wear-os-apps/)

Comment: The problem is that I need to write an application that will download a watch face from a third-party resource from a link. More precisely, it is, but the code that works on the phone does not work on wearable devices.

Comment: Didn't understood, not even sure it is possible. If you found a solution, please share it here.